# Excel: URL with normal Text in a Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, url

How can you add an HTML URL to a cell with normal text?

I have a cell with normal text, but want to add a URL, but I don't want the whole cell to be the URL.

i.e.

> Please go to this link: `www.123.com`

When I type that into a cell, it doesn;t let me put the hyperlink in.

So the user would double click in the cell, then click the hyperlink.

Is there any easy way to do this, without using macros?

Comment: How do you mean a friendly_name?

Comment: Fantastic @pnuts (+1), that worked correctly. thanks :) - but it is also the same as right clicking the cell and selecting `hyperlink`, and doing it that way... without the use of formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have normal text and a hyperlink in the same cell. Either it will be entirely text or entirely a hyperlink.

Depending on the formatting of your sheet, you may be able to enter "Please go to this link:" in one cell, sizing the cell so that it is just big enough for the text, and in the cell on the right have the hyperlink to "www.123.com".

Comment: Thank you, I did think it was not possible. It was worth asking though.